# Thinkpad 11e Hard Lockup Using Multimedia Apps

Tags: xubuntu, 15.10, thinkpad, multimedia, lockup

Xubuntu 15.10 install on a Thinkpad 11e is locking up (entire system freezes) while using multimedia applications, or multimedia websites with Chrome.  This has happened while playing games (OpenTTD, Factorio), Youtube, and iHeart.  It seems to be a random amount of time before starting it and the crash.  I have seen anywhere from 3 minutes (most likely) to 30 minutes (very rare).

I am able to run Phoronix doing some graphics tests (synthetic benchmarks) for a few hours with no issue.  Once I tried Youtube, almost locked up almost instantly.

I ran some tests from "stress" with no issues.

I played some MP3 files with qmmp and rhythmbox for over an hour and a half (and for a while, simultaneously).  I then switched to OpenTTD, updated some assets in the game, and then it locked up again while sitting on the main menu.

This install is a transplant from a previous laptop that didn't have any issues.  Besides getting the wireless card working on the previous computer, there has been no other serious changes.

Comment: What makes you believe that it is the sound system?

Comment: @Takkat Best guess, they been sure fire ways to do it.  I have not had any lockups not doing them.  I'm currently looking up ways I can isolate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing a kernel bug with the Intel Baytrail processors that this line of laptops use:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

The workaround is to pass `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` as a boot parameter as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/803649/527764)