# Constant Lockups

Tags: kernel, graphics

This specific issue isn't tied to just Ubuntu, It seems to effect a whole range of distributions. As I use Ubuntu as my main OS I ask this question here.

The issue is to do with soft locks and constant freezing I can't quite work out what the issue is. It may be a kernel bug, or it might just be tied to specific CPUs.

I've ruled out the possibility of it being my hardware, my brand new laptop has the exact same issue, and so do my older 1151 socket computer.

This issue doesn't seem to happen on my spare core 2 duo machine that I've used with Ubuntu for some time.

Both my desktop and laptop have different processors and different graphics cards, one being a AMD R7 360 and the other being integrated so it can't be graphic driver related.

My desktops CPU is a Haswell 1150 LGA Intel Core I3 4170.
My laptop has a baytrail can't remember the rest, but it's a Intel pentium.

Completely ruled out ram as being the issue two, tested ram on both the laptop and desktop, put new sticks in. Hard drives have been tested, replaced them not long ago as general maintenance.

These freezes happen at random, and always require a hard reset, or they mouse just jumps very slowly than freezes.

I was thinking it could be the hard drive, as the hard drive light usually stays red before the lockup, but it's a brand new SSD and windows seems to work absolutely fine, and even happens with a LIVE USB with the hard drive taken out.

Older Linux distros like puppy linux don't seem to have this issue on either of my hardware, so I'm tying it to a kernel bug.

I surely can't be the only one with this issues, is there any known fixes for this? updating the kernel doesn't really do anything other than improve performance.

Only difference between the two computers is that, desktop seems to freeze randomly every couple hours, while my laptop would be anywhere from 10 minutes, to an hour.

I should add I think its related to this.
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

Comment: if you think it is the c-state bug, then try [the workaround](http://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/16-04-lts-freezes-on-hp-laptop-w-pentium-n3540-2-16ghz-x-4-and-intel-bay-trai)

Comment: I'll give it a try on my laptop, :)

Comment: please could you report back (ping me like this @Zanna ) so I can add your processor to my list if it works

Comment: @Zanna I'll have to keep the laptop running a couple hours, to see if it fixes it.

Comment: I know that - you should test it for a day at least before you are sure it works :)

Comment: Please let me know if it worked out for you!

Comment: Laptop went flat after 12 hours, doesn't seem to lock up after the fix. The Processor is Intel Pentium N3540 @ 2.16 Bay Trail.

Comment: it's definitely the c-state bug :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wonder if this is the same bug effecting my I3 :)

Comment: I don't think Haswell have the issue, but let me know if it helps on that and I will add to my list. If it doesn't help, could you either a. ask a new question or b. edit the part about your laptop out of the question so it's just about the desktop

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad we fixed half of your problem at least :)