# Ubuntu 16.04 Freezes at login screen

Tags: boot, drivers, dell, login-screen

I am running ubuntu 16.04 in a dual-boot with Windows 10.  The windows 10 boots without problem, so it's not a hardware issue.  I did the update of ubuntu and rebooted my machine as requested.  Now -every- time I get to the login screen the machine freezes. My machine is a Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Series.  [These are the hardwarde specs for my machine](https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-inspiron-15-3000-series-laptop-computer-fncwc002s/specs/).

The solutions I have tried so far are:

1. booting in recovery mode and running the file system check tool
2. booting in recovery mode and booting in failsafegraphics mode.
3. booting from an earlier kernel  (also repeating #1 and #2) using an earlier kernel.
4. I tried booting using (upstart) but the screen just goes black and never boots.

This could very easily be a graphic driver problem, but I have no idea how to fix it.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated... thanks.

**UPDATE:**  My computer is definitely affected by the c-state bug.  However, my machine hangs before I can boot and open a terminal to fix the bug.  I tried the temporary edit to grub to pass a the kernel boot parameter, but it simply doesn't work.

Can someone give me instructions on how to use an ubuntu livecd  to access my machines grub file so that I can make edits [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail)? btw, I use an encrypted home folder... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many options you can try:

- boot your kernel with nomodeset and/or try to remove quite and splash to see more output (you should try this temporary on grub boot menu -> press e to edit the current entry -> modify the linux line (like suggested) -> press ctrl+x to boot with the modification)
- when the system is up, try to switch terminal with ctrl+alt+f1 and check if you come to a text terminal.
- try discover the problem in recovery mode by reading the log files /var/log/syslog and /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Hope this helps to get closer to the solution ;-)