# Can't boot ubuntu after update, black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, apt, grub2, updates

English isn't my first language, So I will try my best to convey the problem, I performed an update in terminal I did the following

sudo apt-update

sudo apt-upgrade

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt autoclean

sudo apt clean

then I did a reboot, and now I am unable to boot Ubuntu, I am stuck at the GRUB menu that appears at startup, it has the following options

Ubuntu

Advanced options for Ubuntu

Windows Boot Manager

System Setup

I select ubuntu from the GRUB menu at startup, hit enter, I get a black screen with no error messages I can't get out of the black screen, it doesn't respond to any input from the keyboard, I can only restart the laptop by pressing & holding the power button

Comment: select Advanced Options, then choose a kernel image from the options you will be given. start from the first on top and descend if you still get a blank screen. report back :)

Comment: I get the following message on both kernel options  Loading initial ramdisk . I can only enter recovery mode.

Comment: I believe you have a graphics card driver problem. Try this -> https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/ or -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029604/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-hangs-on-login-screen

Comment: I tried the above , no luck. Some more information, my system has HD Graphics 515,  driver = i915_bpo

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049151/ubuntu-18-04-freeze-on-login-screen-shutdown-and-restart-gdm-vs-lightdm

Comment: Plugging in AC adaptor works for some reason I found it here look for 'user175985' answer
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145856/ubuntu-18-04-fails-to-boot-even-in-recovery-mode-stuck-on-loading-initial-ram-d/1146150#1146150

Comment: It is a temporary solution but It is working so far I have done multiple restarts with adaptor plugged in and it boots up with no problems, when I try booting without  adaptor plugged in it stops booting, so far  this is 100% reproducable, but windows is booting fine regardless of weather the adapter is plugged in or not, so it doesn't seem to be a hardware problem, it is clearly something specific to Ubuntu or GRUB

Comment: Please add a new question, state this problem from the start

Comment: Will add a new question soon, so far I have reinstalled ubuntu and the problem went away, but after apt-upgrade it came back. So for now I have reinstalled ubuntu again and will not upgrade until I find a solution as the problem appears after upgrade.