# My lubuntu is not working properly (I think that is My graphic card)

Tags: lubuntu, intel

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04, I like this SO, but I'm feeling that my system is not working fine. My processor is a Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2930 @ 1.83GHz I Updated my BIOS and my system is working better (Motherboard: X451MA), but not so good.

I think that is my graphic card driver. Because when I try to play a video it freeze and then start from the point that the video stopped and the reproduction is not so good. The quality isn't good even if I try to watch a 720p video.

I did some tests and here is the results:

$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5286 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Do I need to download this microcode? how to install it?
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/pt-br/download/26925/Arquivo-de-dados-de-micro-c-digo-de-processador-para-Linux-?product=81073

## dmesg | grep microcode

```
[    1.828507] microcode: sig=0x30678, pf=0x8, revision=0x829
[    1.828744] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.
[ 4968.068075] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:30678 TIME 1501257529 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 829
[ 4968.068120] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:30678 TIME 1501257529 SOCKET 0 APIC 2 microcode 829
[ 4968.068161] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:30678 TIME 1501257529 SOCKET 0 APIC 4 microcode 829
[ 4968.068207] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:30678 TIME 1501257529 SOCKET 0 APIC 6 microcode 829
[ 4968.152606] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:30678 TIME 1501257529 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 829
[ 4968.152655] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:30678 TIME 1501257529 SOCKET 0 APIC 2 microcode 829
[ 4968.152697] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:30678 TIME 1501257529 SOCKET 0 APIC 4 microcode 829
[ 4968.152738] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:30678 TIME 1501257529 SOCKET 0 APIC 6 microcode 829
```

I think that my graphic board is not Ok, Intel Graphics is not compatible with my hardware.

modinfo Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display:

```
[1] 2418
modinfo: ERROR: Module Intel not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module Corporation not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module Atom not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module Processor not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module Z36xxx/Z37xxx not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module Series not found.
modinfo: ERROR: Module Graphics not found.
Comando 'Display' não encontrado, você quis dizer:
 Comando 'display' do pacote 'graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat' (universe)
 Comando 'display' do pacote 'imagemagick' (main)
Display: comando não encontrado
[1]+  Fim da execução com status 1      modinfo Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics
```

dmesg | egrep -i 'failed|error|warn'

```
[    0.000000] ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): 32/64X length mismatch in FADT/Gpe0Block: 128/32 (20160422/tbfadt-624)
[    0.228496] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    8.727154] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
```

More Info

```
System:    Host: leandrort-X451MA Kernel: 4.10.0-28-generic i686 (32 bit)
           Desktop: LXDE (Openbox 3.6.1) Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: X451MA v: 1.0
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X451MA v: 1.0
           Bios: American Megatrends v: X451MA.216 date: 04/10/2015
CPU:       Quad core Intel Celeron N2930 (-MCP-) speed/max: 499/2165 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: vesa (unloaded: fbdev)
           Resolution: 1368x768@0.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
Network:   Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: ath9k
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (1.4% used)
Info:      Processes: 165 Uptime: 21 min Memory: 704.4/3928.0MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

That's all guys. I hope that you can help me, Thanks!

Hello @heynnema, here the results, thank you.

free  -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3,8G        1,0G        2,0G         50M        850M        2,4G
Swap:          3,9G          0B        3,9G
```

swapon -s

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda6                               partition   4076540 0   -1
```

sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfdecba05

Dispositivo Inicializar     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Tipo
/dev/sda1   *                2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2                 1026048 510808063 509782016 243,1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3               510810110 976771071 465960962 222,2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5               510810112 968616752 457806641 218,3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6               968617984 976771071   8153088   3,9G 82 Linux swap / Sol

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Xorg configuration:
etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

I tried to disable hardware acceleration, but I can't watch videos in full screen. Also, I can't install Intel Graphics because my video card is not compatible with the software.

---

```
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/about/supported-hardware
```

**FIXED**

I created a xorg configuration with this command line in terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

and put this

```
Section "Device"
       Identifier "Intel Graphics"
       Driver     "intel"
       Option     "NoAccel"   "uxa"
       Option     "DRI"       "False"
       Option     "TearFree"  "true"
    EndSection
```

Thank you guys. Thank you @heynnema

Comment: What is your actual question? Whenever posting in any Stack Exchange site try to put a summarized short question under the information you include.

Comment: Hello, I think that my graphic card is not working so well, I'm using lubuntu around 2 weeks. I need to know how to make it work fine. thanks.

Comment: that's good now you can edit your question and put it right before "That's all guys. I hope that you can help me, Thanks!".

Comment: but without "hello" obviously

Comment: You need to tell us what the **symptom** is, not what you think the problem is. ie: screen distorts, or screen goes black, or system won't boot, etc.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, but I think that my system is not working fine cause the movies that I tried to watch start and freeze for some seconds (1 or 2 seconds) after some seconds of reproduction, then they start again from the point that they stopped. I'm sorry Tooniis I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: OK, so choppy video. Is this video from the net, or a local video?

Comment: ps: wired network connection, or wireless. If wireless, are you using WPA2-AES? What connection speeds are you getting?

Comment: Local video, I have videos in my hard drive, my internet is wireless, 10 mb/s - WPA/WPA2.

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `free -h`, `swapon -s`, and `sudo fdisk -l`. Please copy/paste that output into your question, not the comments please. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with those numbers. There may be something wrong with ffmpeg or missing codecs, but I'm not an expert on this. Somebody else will need to chime in. Sorry. Just curious, what player do you use to play movies?

Comment: Hello @heynnema, I'm using Vlc. I created a xorg configuration (it is in my question), with this configuration video card seems that is ok, but I can't watch movies in full screen. I disabled hardware acceleration, but it's not the solution. Have a nice sunday.

Answer (score 2):

- Assure that `intel-microcode` is installed (I just noticed that you already have this installed.)

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
reboot
```

- You have an Intel Bay Trail processor, and it's effected by the c-state bug. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail for the fix.

Comment: Thank you, Heynnema, I did this and this message appeared:
intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20151106.1).

Comment: I edited the GRUB as suggested in the link. But the problem continue, I think that my video card isn't working fine. Many thanks.