# Brand new desktop randomly powers off

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu

Three or four days ago I was in Best Buy and bought a new Desktop...basically on impulse.  It is, to be exact, a Lenovo 310S-08IAP natively running Windows 10.  (https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-310s-08iap-pentium-j4205-1-5-ghz-4-gb-500-gb/specs/)

I got it home, unboxed it and set it up, and powered it up to make sure it worked as intended from the factory.  I used it for some web browsing and a couple of other very brief, routine tasks and everything seemed fine.  So I immediately set about the task of installing Xubuntu on it.

[You can safely skip this entire bracketed section if you like, it's just a little background information.  (I'm fully aware I have a tendency to bloviate in writing, so, it won't hurt my feelings.)

I was unaware at the time of purchase of all the boot configuration changes that came along with, I guess, Windows 8(?).  This is my first new computer in...years.  I have an ancient desktop that's run Xubuntu, exclusively, without problem, for years.  A 2011 Macbook Pro, same situation.  And five Raspberry Pi's which I use to boot various Linux distributions.  My point is, I consider myself a long-time linux fan and a pretty competent user.  I always try to solve any issues I encounter myself because that's how you learn, and, frankly, it's fun and I enjoy doing it.  That said, I'm an electrical engineering student, classes start back tomorrow and I expect free time after today to be at a premium until, basically, next summer.  So I'd like to get this solved ASAP and frankly I'm not really sure where to begin with this one.]

After the installation, I was configuring things to my liking when the machine just powered off.  I booted it back up and began the task anew and after 5 or 10 minutes it happened again.  I thought "that's strange."

So, to this point, my efforts have basically involved removing and reinstalling Xubuntu using various methods.  (Being a brand new machine I wasn't afraid of losing anything important.)  I tried, for instance, setting up partitions (including one with about 10 gigs of swap space) from within Windows, installing Xubuntu, and I had the problem.  I tried partitioning drives from the Xubuntu installer and installing alongside Windows, I have the problem.  I tried wiping the thing from the Xubuntu installer and installing Xubuntu stand alone, I have the problem.  I removed any trace of Xubuntu and reinstalled Windows and the thing runs like a dream.  (Or as close to a dream as a Windows machine can get.) Finally, with both Windows and Xubuntu on the machine, I experience the problem when booted into Xubuntu, but not when booted into Windows.

This post is finally, mercifully, over.  I'm not really sure where to go from here and I would greatly appreciate any help, even if it's just a gentle nudge in the appropriate direction.  Thanks!

Per request, the results of `grep -i -e temp -e therm /var/log/syslog*`:

```
phillip@ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha:~$ grep -i -e temp -e therm /var/log/syslog*
Aug 20 12:44:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    0.022829] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Aug 20 12:44:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 20 12:44:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
Aug 20 12:44:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    1.557352] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
Aug 20 12:44:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    1.557354] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (35 C)
Aug 20 12:44:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service.
Aug 20 12:44:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[748]: 21 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:5c:9 (6:92:9)
Aug 20 12:44:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[748]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Aug 20 12:44:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha sensors[852]: temp1:        +36.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
Aug 20 12:44:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha sensors[852]: coretemp-isa-0000
Aug 20 12:44:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[748]: sysfs read failed constraint_0_max_power_uw
Aug 20 12:44:10 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Aug 20 12:44:10 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
Aug 20 12:58:54 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Aug 20 12:58:54 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 20 13:06:58 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    0.022804] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Aug 20 13:06:58 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 20 13:06:58 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
Aug 20 13:06:58 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    1.555336] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
Aug 20 13:06:58 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    1.555338] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (35 C)
Aug 20 13:06:58 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha sensors[840]: temp1:        +36.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
Aug 20 13:06:58 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha sensors[840]: coretemp-isa-0000
Aug 20 13:06:59 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service.
Aug 20 13:06:59 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[779]: 21 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:5c:9 (6:92:9)
Aug 20 13:06:59 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[779]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Aug 20 13:06:59 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[779]: sysfs read failed constraint_0_max_power_uw
Aug 20 13:07:07 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Aug 20 13:07:07 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
Aug 20 17:13:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 20 17:13:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    0.022793] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Aug 20 17:13:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
Aug 20 17:13:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    1.550742] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
Aug 20 17:13:00 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    1.550744] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (28 C)
Aug 20 17:13:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service.
Aug 20 17:13:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[799]: 21 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:5c:9 (6:92:9)
Aug 20 17:13:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[799]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Aug 20 17:13:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha sensors[878]: temp1:        +30.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
Aug 20 17:13:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha sensors[878]: coretemp-isa-0000
Aug 20 17:13:01 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[799]: sysfs read failed constraint_0_max_power_uw
Aug 20 17:13:10 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Aug 20 17:13:10 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
Aug 20 17:17:50 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 20 17:17:50 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Stopping Thermal Daemon Service...
Aug 20 17:17:50 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[799]: Terminating ...
Aug 20 17:18:21 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 20 17:18:21 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
Aug 20 17:18:21 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha sensors[850]: temp1:        +34.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
Aug 20 17:18:21 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha sensors[850]: coretemp-isa-0000
Aug 20 17:18:21 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    0.022905] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Aug 20 17:18:21 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    1.551030] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
Aug 20 17:18:21 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha kernel: [    1.551032] ACPI: Thermal Zone [TZ01] (32 C)
Aug 20 17:18:22 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service.
Aug 20 17:18:22 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[846]: 21 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:5c:9 (6:92:9)
Aug 20 17:18:22 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[846]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Aug 20 17:18:22 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha thermald[846]: sysfs read failed constraint_0_max_power_uw
Aug 20 17:18:30 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
Aug 20 17:18:30 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
Aug 20 17:33:23 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Aug 20 17:33:23 ZZ9-Plural-Z-Alpha systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

Comment: The only way this is an Ubuntu issue is if the CPU or other motherboard cooling is not operating correctly under Ubuntu, but works correctly in Windows.  The shutdown after a short running time is classic thermal issues.

Comment: Probably same issue as [BayTrail processors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail)

Comment: I considered a thermal problem.  Is there anyway I can diagnose it/anything I can do about it?

Comment: In `terminal` do `grep -i -e temp -e therm /var/log/syslog*`. Copy/paste those results into your question please, not in the comments. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the Pentium J4205 is not on the list of Bay Trail processors.

Comment: Post updated as per your request.

For whatever it's worth to anyone keeping score (so to speak), about an hour ago I implemented the fix for the problem found in the link provided by @WinEunuuchs2Unix , and the thing has been running consistently and without issue since then.  I guess it's still to early to say anything definite, but that is far, far longer than it's stayed powered on up to this point, so, fingers crossed.

Comment: @heynnema I believe it's the successor to BayTrail and CherryTrail and as such likely prone to the same "features". Of course I don't know for sure, just a hunch.

Comment: Still going strong.  I'm starting to believe this issue is fixed (thanks @WinEunuuchs) , but I'll keep my fingers crossed for a while longer just to be sure.  Thanks everyone else, as well.  I was preparing myself for a long, arduous battle but if this fix holds I'd say I got off pretty easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processor is the "Apollo Lake" Intel family and may be effected by the Intel "Bay Trail" bug: [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail).

Here is one summary of Intel CPU families starting with "Bay Trail" by an [Intel employee](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-Bay-Trail-Cherry-Trail-Braswell-and-Apollo-Lake):

> Disclaimer: I work for Intel Corporation. The information I'm using to
>   answer this question comes from publicly-available sources.
>
> When looking for information on Intel’s hardware products, Intel®
>   Product Specifications should be your first stop. Especially for
>   comparing features or launch/discontinuance dates, this site should
>   have what you're looking for.
>
> Bay Trail: Launched Q3 2013
>
> Cherry Trail: Launched Q1 2016
>
> Braswell: Launched Q1 2016
>
> Apollo Lake: Launched Q3 2016

Based on OP comments it appears likely the Pentium J4205 suffers from the same Bay Trail bug.

Comment: I implemented the fix in your link a couple of hours ago and it's still going strong.  I'm (cautiously) beginning to expect you nailed this one.  Thanks for your help!