# What displaylink driver is bundled with Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, dkms, displaylink

I am working on a solution that is using a DisplayLink touch monitor (ELO 0700L). Ubuntu 16.04 desktop detected this monitor without any need to install the official DisplayLink driver. My solution is based on chromium-browser running in full screen, kiosk mode. But unfortunately, the system freezes after around 10-12 hours (not ICMP PINGs are answered). I have upgraded the installation and I have disabled GPU in chrome. But I don't know if these will help or not. I'll see in half a day.
I will have to assess if DisplayLink could be the cause. Unfortunately, I can not identify the DisplayLink related components in the system. As if there would be a totally different "driver" than the official one. Not even DKMS is installed, which is required for previous versions too.

[image: Installation script output]

What could be the current driver?
Or any other suggestion what to check, how to determine what is causing the ice age?

Comment: What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'` and `lsmod`?

Comment: `VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [8086:0f31] (rev 11)`... which is definitely not the monitor. No other monitor is connected at all. lsmod gives a quite long list, what should I look for?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: You have a Z series Bay Trail CPU. That's the problem, not the included Displaylink drivers, if any, or anything else.

Comment: @MichaelBay. You mean the **Z series Bay Trail CPU** is causing the system to freeze? Well, this is an industrial mini PC, with no other CPU option... and anyway it is given. Can't change it. By the way, with Windows 10 IoT Enetrprise it is not freezing. And what solution do you suggest?

Comment: @MichaelBay: I found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail according to which this can be a CPU related bug. I have found this grub setting somewhere already and I made the change. Now I will check what happened in 18 hours. Is it still there in 17.x?

Comment: @MichaelBay: it looks, that the `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` workaround has not solved my problem. System still freezing but only after 28 hours.... Any suggestion?