# Flickering windows and video freezing

Tags: gnome, freeze, flicker

I have recently updated for Ubuntu 17.10, I have the following issues since then:

- Windows flickers when I open/resize them, with a thick black lines
  blinking around them
- After a while, videos tend to freeze the
  computer. The mouse/keyboard are no more responding, although the
  sound is still playing.

I am using the new default Gnome desktop, and also I do not have a super fancy graphic card, I don't think my problems are related to a lack of resources:

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:32 mémoire:f7800000-f7bfffff mémoire:e0000000-efffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

I followed the instructions on these threads:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1405260&p=10342739#post10342739
- [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail/803649#803649)

But it did not fix the issue. In particular, I cannot use gstreamer-properties since gnome-video does not seem to be an official package since Ubuntu 14.Does anyone has an idea about what to do?

Comment: I believe Gnome session defaults to Wayland when supported — have you tried choosing X11 instead?

Comment: I didn' know X11 was no more the default in Ubuntu 17. After a couple of searches, I found that you can switch back to X11 by uncommenting the following line in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`: `#WaylandEnable=false`. Everything seems to be ok so far. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: actually no need to edit anything — you can just choose X11 session on login screen, and after the next reboot it would be the default session. As for the problem, since picking X11 session fixed it, you can probably try latest drivers, and if it didn't fix the problem, report a bug.