# Ubuntu 18 Freezing the Whole Computer all the time

Tags: freeze, 18.04

I'm quite new in Ubuntu, but anyway, I have installed the second OS as Ubuntu and the first attempt lead to the freezing Ubuntu all the time, I reinstalled and I got the same story.
I have tried:
[What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)
[System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail)
But it doesn't work. And I cannot manage even to launch the terminal after logging in.
My computer: Asus Vivobook pro, Intel i7-7700hq and I have also Windows 10 Home.

Any idea?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this a new install of Ubuntu 18.04, or did you upgrade?  Have you made any changes since installing (add/remove packages, change display drivers, etc)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Which of the existing answers to those existing questions did you use and what were the results?

Comment: Hello @64pi0r and Fabby, so while installation (I downloaded the most recent installation from this website) I checked the box to upgrade while installation and I didn't touch any driver, because basically I couldn't, only one thing which I could manage to try is: to change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1". Thank you for you involvement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I7-7700HQ is **not** a Bay Trail CPU

Answer (score 1):

Download the 18.04 .iso and load a recently formatted usb drive with the image.  Boot from the usb and select to 'Try Ubuntu without installing'.

You're doing this to check if there is any lag/freezing/etc.  If the problem exists when booted from usb image, we know the issue is being caused by either a hardware issue, or by a default configuration issue shipped with 18.04.  This will likely be harder to diagnose and correct.

If the problem does not happen when booted from usb image, then we know the issue is being caused by a local configuration (software) on your computer.  This should be easier to fix.

If you don't have anything important on your workstation, this would be a convenient time to do a fresh install (format start over).  Likely resolving the problem.  Although, please be aware this will delete any existing files/configurations/etc on your old Ubuntu installation.