# Install Ubuntu 18.10 in Asus Aptio Notebook with Preinstalled Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu in a Asus Aptio notebook with preinstalled Windows 8.1. It has a USB drive. So, I created an installer in a USB drive and tried to install from it. However, the notebook refuses to boot from USB drive and I am brought back to setup utility every time I choose the "boot from USB option".

The steps so far:

1. Disable secure boot from setup utility.
2. Choose USB as the first boot option (the USB drive is being recognized perfectly with brand name shown).
3. Save changes and exit.

But, I am brought to Windows after a reboot.

If I force the "boot from USB" inside setup using Boot Override, I am simply brought back to setup.

Other sleuthing which have failed:

1. This notebook has Intel Atom® Processor Z3740, which as per [this page](https://ark.intel.com/products/76759/Intel-Atom-Processor-Z3740-2M-Cache-up-to-1-86-GHz-), is a 64 bit processor. So, Ubuntu 18.10 should be alright.
2. The notebook has 2 GB RAM, show this [should be okay](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) as well.
3. The setup has no option for legacy boot or CSM.

Feeling a bit clueless.

**Edit 1**

Out of sheer frustration, I created the installation media in a second USB drive. When this also refused to boot in the notebook, I tried this in another computer, and it booted fine.

**Edit 2**

No improvement with lubuntu (lubuntu Desktop 64-bit).

**Edit 3**

Notebook model: [ASUS Transformer Book T100TA](https://www.asus.com/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T100TA/)

```
Bios Information
Bios Vendor         American Megatrends
Version             314
GOP Version         7.1.1005
EC Version          G1BT1500
```

**Edit 4**

The [WinSetupFromUSB](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/) approach (choosing the `AutoFormat with FBInst` and checking the `Force CHS` option) failed exactly the same way. I am simply brought back to setup.

Comment: How did you create the install media?  Does it work in other computers? Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  Did you run media-check on the install media?

Comment: 2G of ram may be too little.  Try Lubuntu and see if that works for you.  How did you create the install media? -- you're sure it's not just a legacy insatll, which would fail on your machine.

Comment: I used the startup disk creator. Actually, I tried both legacy and secure boot s. Both failed.

Comment: What is the actual model # of your Asus Aptio notebook? Bios version? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek Please see **Edit 3**.

Comment: Sadly you are running the most recent BIOS (v.314) available for your system and it doesn't appear they did anything to make things better for anything other than Windows 10. One thing you could try that I've had some success with (with buggy BIOS) is to create a  boot-able stick with the ISO **from Windows** using [WinSetupFromUSB](http://www.winsetupfromusb.com/downloads/)  and choosing the AutoFormat with FBInst and checking the `Force CHS ` option. If that doesn't work for you the only other alternative I can think of  is to transfer the drive to another system temporarily for installation

Comment: @ElderGeek The WinSetupFromUSB approach failed exactly the same way. 
Transferring the drive to another system temporarily seems a bit of a tall order. Let me think about it.

Comment: Further research indicates that Asus calling this a notebook is a bit of a stretch. It's more of a glorified tablet. Be that as it may [this post may help you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail) as according to the specs from Asus your device has a "Bay Trail CPU"

Comment: This [might also be useful](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2274298.html)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to install a 32-bit version*. The T100TA has a 64-bit processor, but is still restricted to 32-bit for its OS because of the lack of 64-bit UEFI and a legacy boot option.

*If you'd really like to, though, it *is* possible to install a 64-bit Linux distro with 32-bit UEFI, but it's a little more work; for example, there's the multiarch Debian build [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/multi-arch/iso-cd/). Instructions on its installation [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/715843/238803). Make sure "launch CSM" is enabled in your BIOS, by the way.

Comment: No luck with 32-bit version of lubuntu.

Comment: @Masroor Interesting. I'm not familiar with the program you're using for the install media, so I recommend Rufus, which has the option "GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer" during creation.

Comment: I use [Startup Disk Creator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_Disk_Creator). This has not failed me even once in all these years.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed ubuntu on an Asus.  Insert the usb first, then try holding down the f2 key and then turn on the laptop, keep holding f2 until the bios comes up and change the boot sequence to have the usb be the first item in the list.  Good Luck.