# Ubuntu Freezing when idle

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu

I have some Point of Sale computers I need to get linux working. I started with Lubuntu but it kept freezing when Idle. Next step was to try ubuntu desktop 18.04 but i am having the same freezing issues. Is there any way I can solve this. the specs of the machines are below.I turned off all power saving settings I could find

[Machine Specs](https://www.okpos.co.kr/eng/solution/solution_010107.php)

Comment: Try looking at this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail/803649#803649

Comment: it seems like a hardware issue. btw, is there any chance you're describing ubuntu's `sleep on inactivity` feature as freeze? does your system wake up after you move mouse / touch the screen?