# Ubuntu 19.04 boots to systemd and then freezes after Gnome reload

Tags: boot, gnome, 19.04, tty

After restarting Gnome (with `alt+f2` and then entering r) Ubuntu will sometimes go's to a empty tty and become unresponsive, upon rebooting a tty opens spits out a bunch of text (that seems to be generated from systemd) and quickly becomes unresponsive (not always at the same line of text) and the system needs to be shutdown with the power button, after the reboot the system will open a tty and and spit out a bunch of messages I think is from systemd.

most of the messages look something like this:

`[   ok   ] reached starting bluetooth`

I have had this problem three times now and each time I have had to totally reinstall Ubuntu from a live usb drive.

My system runs a intel Celeron cpu with a Bay Trail igpu incase that important.

Command outputs from runing the kernel in recovery mode to access a terminal:
`ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
output :
`ls: cannot access ‘/root/.local/share/gnome-extensions’ : No such file or directory`
Filestructure ends at `-/.local/share`

`ls -al /home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
output :
`ls: cannot access ‘/home/username/.local/share/gnome-extensions’ : No such file or directory`
Filestructure ends at `-/.local/share/gnome-shell`

`free -h`
output :
`mem: total 3.7gi used 77mi free 3.5gi shared 1.0mi buff/cache 133mi available 3.5gi`
`swap: total 5.6gi used 0b free 5.6gi`

`ls -alt /var/crash`
output :
`total 8`
`drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 apr 16 15:10 ..`
`drwxrwsrwt 2 root whoopsie 4096  apr 16 15:04 .`
This system has never run in april.

`sudo fsck -f /dev/sda7` (sda7 is my Linux filesystem)
output :
`fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.6 (5-Mar-2019)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda7: 195643/10821632 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 2679734/43274170 blocks` this command was run from a terminal in a live USB.

A video of the system failing to boot and me powering the system uff should be [here](https://streamable.com/8rfoo)  (its to long for imgur).

When booting Ubuntu with `nomodeset` instead of `quiet splash` and reading the resulting text I noticed a pattern of
`Stopping X...`
`[  ok  ]Stopped X.`
`Starting X...`
`[  ok  ]Starting X.`
Were X is something like `WPA supplicant`
The system eventually hangs on the line
`[  ok  ]Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities`
There where also three messages with a timer they were
`A start job is running for Daily apt download activities`this one showed up twice
`A start job is running for Daily apt upgrade and clean activities`this one lasted  minutes

[Screenshots of disk SMART readout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6tuB.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to fix the issue but I did figure out what triggers it, for me at least this issue is caused by refreshing the gnome shell while [Meow](https://pnmougel.github.io/meow/) open or using the icon editing functionality of Meow. So maybe don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You **may** have this problem...

reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail

---

You have an Intel "Bay Trail" processor that has a bug.

In `terminal`...

We edit a startup parameter in GRUB with:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

Then:

```
sudo update-grub

reboot
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99072/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-19-04-boots-to-systemd-and-then-freezes).