# Can't install Ubuntu on Bay Trail, it keep freezing on first minute

Tags: boot, grub2, 19.10, migration

Currently, I'm using Windows 7 as my Operating System. But I want migrate from Windows to Ubuntu totally. So, I want to fresh Install an Ubuntu OS.

My laptop (ASUS X453MA), has a Bay Trail proccesor. I'm using a flashdisk to install the Ubuntu.

When I reboot my laptop, the Ubuntu 19.10 on my flashdisk is working perfectly. It show Ubuntu loading screen, and of course I can try Ubuntu for some seconds.

Yes from some seconds, and the problem is, when I try Ubuntu for a minute, it keep freezing randomly. Even when I tried to install, it keep freezing at select keyboard or partition steps.

As [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/803649/1017221) say, it causes Bay Trail affected by c-state bug. And the solution is set `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` in GRUB.

What I'm asking is, Is possible my Laptop using Ubuntu? How to set the `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` while I'm trying to install Ubuntu?

I'm totally new to Ubuntu / Linux.

Comment: The ISO checksum is match, I also test the flashdisc Ubuntu installer at Ubuntu welcome screen (I forgot the menu name). Everything seems ok with the flasdisc, ISO, and installer.

Comment: At the grub menu press `e` to edit command line option for `Try Ubuntu` or `Install Ubuntu` options.

Comment: what / where is "grub menu"? @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: @K7AAY Even I point to that question in mine. My question is different. I ask for where to set the ```intel_idle.max_cstate=1``` based on an answer on that question.

Comment: @K7AAY OP already knows what is in the duplicate candidate. OP doesn't know how to apply grub command line override to Live USB.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer my own question.*

How to set `intle_idle.max_cstate=1` or other boot paramater on live USB installer.

**Option 1 - Add paramater in GRUB menu (Recommended)**

GRUB is a boot loader. Simplicity: menu that appear after booting that show you some option like "Try Ubuntu Without Installing" and "Install Ubuntu".

Point to an option (use `up` and down `arrow`) that you want boot into. Don't press `enter`! instead press '`e`' for edit command line boot option.

After pressing `e`, now it show like editor in command line. Find a line that start with `linux` and usually end with `---`. It looks like this:

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet splash ---
```

From this line, you can add boot parameter. Place the paramater before ---. So, if you want to add intle_idle.max_cstate=1 or other paramaters, the line now should be like this:

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet splash nomodeset intel_idle.max_cstate=1 ---
```

If you done. Press `f10` to boot into Ubuntu.

**Option 2 - Edit *grub.cfg* directly**

This is a '*dirty*' way because you directly edit the *grub.cfg* on installer sources.

The *grub.cfg* is located at `USBINSTALLER->boot->grub` folder. In that location, you can find and edit the *grub.cfg*.

The file is something like this:

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
...
```

Next step is edit the file and add boot paramater to linux line like the **Option 1**. Save if you done. And you can boot into Ubuntu directly without adding paramater from GRUB.