# Using syslog to diagnose a crash

Tags: kernel, crash, syslog

This is more of a request for experienced eyeballs than a coherent question.

I work at a library and we use a little Intel Atom $100 computer from China to show a looping LibreOffice Impress slideshow on an HDMI-enabled TV.

I noticed tonight that the slide wasn't advancing no matter how long I looked at it. Tried to SSH in, no response. (We run the computer without mouse or keyboard attached and just use SSH and VNC.)

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 but it might be with a newer kernel than standard. Some of the reasons for doing this: I was having issues getting sound to come out over HDMI, and I was also having issues with video playback (especially within LibreOffice Impress presentations). Right now we're down to a slient slideshow so if I have to roll back the kernel (if that's possible), it's probably not the end of the world.

I put the ~300KB of /var/log/syslog.1 logs in a Pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/PiU8MnTX
(Things go to pot at 16:38 Nov 18.)

But here are the last few entries:

`Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051044] RIP: 0033:0x7f493aacf0b4
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051054] Code: c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 54 55 49 89 d4 53 48 89 f5 89 fb 48 83 ec 10 e8 3b 06 02 00 4c 89 e2 41 89 c0 48 89 ee 89 df 31 c0 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 38 44 89 c7 48 89 44 24 08 e8 77 06 02 00 48
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051060] RSP: 002b:00007fff197ac7a0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051070] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000021 RCX: 00007f493aacf0b4
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051076] RDX: 0000000000001000 RSI: 0000560b853093b0 RDI: 0000000000000021
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051081] RBP: 0000560b853093b0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051087] R10: 0000560b8529d010 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000001000
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051093] R13: 0000000000001001 R14: 0000000000000d68 R15: 0000000000001001
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051105] ---[ end trace 3051b4539069419d ]---
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051117] i2c_designware 808622C1:06: couldn't acquire bus ownership
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051136] axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_fuel_gauge: axp288 reg read err:-110
Nov 18 16:13:53 circtv kernel: [24890.051167] power_supply axp288_fuel_gauge: driver failed to report 'present' property: -110`

Then there's a whole bunch of funny \00\00s, maybe from where it crashed or I held down the power button so it would shut off.

`\00\00\00\00\00\00Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd-modules-load[339]: Inserted module 'lp'
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv ureadahead[337]: ureadahead: Error while tracing: No such file or directory
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd-modules-load[339]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd-modules-load[339]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Activated swap /swapfile.
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 91...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-system-monitor, revision 107...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core18, revision 1265...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1353...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-characters, revision 367...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core, revision 8039...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 110...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core18, revision 1223...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1313...
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x411, date = 2019-04-23
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.2.0+ (root@caaf6e0195cc) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04)) #1 SMP Sat Jul 13 13:16:00 UTC 2019
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.2.0+ root=UUID=0601cece-43b2-465d-8d21-f8f57b540383 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000008efff] usable
Nov 19 18:27:31 circtv kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000008f000-0x000000000008ffff] ACPI NVS`

Comment: Scroll back through /var/log/syslog.1 to the `---[ begin trace 3051b4539069419d ]---` line. Copy the entire trace to the "end trace" line and post it in your question. Or copy the entire trace into a pastebin and post a link. The minute or two before the trace begins might be helpful, too. Check your /var/crash directory for a .crash file matching the crash time. If so, simply copy that instead of wandering through syslog.

Comment: It just says `[ end trace ... ]` a bunch of times and never `[ begin trace ... ]`. But I put the whole thing in a Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/PiU8MnTX

Things go to pot at 16:38 Nov 18.

My /var/crash is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message is found in this [bug report](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/708773/).

> ```
> i2c_designware 808622C1:06: punit semaphore timed out, resetting
> i2c_designware 808622C1:06: PUNIT SEM: 2
> i2c_designware 808622C1:06: couldn't acquire bus ownership
> axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_fuel_gauge: axp288 reg read err:-110
> axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_fuel_gauge: PWR STAT read failed:-110
> usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
> usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
> usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
> i2c_designware 808622C1:06: punit semaphore timed out, resetting
> i2c_designware 808622C1:06: PUNIT SEM: 0
> i2c_designware 808622C1:06: couldn't acquire bus ownership
> axp288_fuel_gauge axp288_fuel_gauge: IIO channel read error: fffffffb, 0
> power_supply axp288_fuel_gauge: driver failed to report `voltage_now' property: -5
> ***SYSTEM FREEZE***
> ```

The title of the bug report is:

- #### [v2,4/5] i2c: designware-baytrail: Force the CPU to C1 state while holding the punit semaphore

The workaroud leads us to this infamous thread in Linux-Land / Ubuntu-Utopia:

- [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail)

Your best bet is to update grub command line (`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`) with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

and then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Wow. This machine has a 4c/4t Intel Atom x5-Z8350, which is supposed to be Cherry Trail. But I'll give it a go! (And upon reading the first link more closely, it seems like it is also a Cherry Trail problem.)

Comment: It's been smooth sailing since that change. Thanks again!