# What process freezes Ubuntu?

Tags: cpu

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
For almost 2 years Ubuntu freezes randomly and I have no clue why and what process is taking over unlimited time. Sometimes the HDD is rubbing continuously for hours and it has to power off the box. But sometimes there is no activity and obviously the cold reboot is needed what the user  user535733 refers to as a kernel crash.

Any process monitors like *top do not help to find the culprit.

I check some log files for the period when froze but nothing relevant. What else to check? Help will be very much appreciated.

```
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0c)
```

and

```
*-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0c
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:96 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:3050(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
```

and

```
 *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3520  @ 2.16GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3520  @ 2.16GHz
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 1451MHz
          capacity: 2415MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 83MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=1
```

Comment: To me, a "freeze" means a kernel crash: No response from keyboard or mouse, no changes to screen for over 10 minutes, no response to REISUB, only recourse after trying all those is a hard power-cycle. A kernel crash is a bug -- developers did not intend the kernel to crash. But from your description, it's not clear what a "freeze" means to you. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1240031/edit) to clarify.

Comment: What is the video-card on the system? Incorrect drivers or kernel commands (within the grub settings) could cause crashes. Another (not related to Ubuntu) cause could be an error in your mother board's firmware (BIOS). I've suffered from random crashes for a year and finally did fresh flash of the firmware with the same version and the problem disappear.

Comment: Also CPU model/make would be good to know.  HDD rubbing for hours is not good.  Might be problem if that is what you mean.  Noise from HDD is usually never good.  If just a wonky process, system monitor and or 'top' command in terminal might point in right direction.

Comment: That is a baytrail CPU with a known bug that causes freezing.   Fix for it at this link.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail

Comment: Should have said a work around that usually works well.  It is not a complete fix.  With my baytrail, when it happens the fan will go to high speed for a few minutes every so often till power off.