# Kubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 random freezes

Tags: kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 18.04 installed on my machine and sometimes it gets frozen randomly and when this happens the only thing I can do is a forced shut down. I have experienced this in Kubuntu 20.04 and in Ubuntu 20.04 too even more frequently.

The only Ubuntu version in which I haven't had this problem is in Ubuntu 18.04. I think this is a problem related with the kernel version but I'm not sure.

These are my pc specs, I have an Intel integrated graphic card:
[image: my pc specs]

This is the partition table:

[image: Partition table]

Comment: You have to check but that CPU looks to be baytrail.  There is a bug that freezes computer.   Google ubuntu baytrail and get the work around.

Comment: Can see this link once you made sure your CPU is baytrail.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail

Comment: Is your system a dual boot?

Comment: Seems your CPU is braswell not baytrail type, so my comments might not work.

Comment: @AkshatZala it is dual boot, I have Windows 10 installed in a different partition.

Comment: @crip659 I already tried what is suggested in that question but after some days the system got frozen again. I upgraded the system to the latest LTS version (20.04.1), I'll see how it goes with this version.

Comment: @JesusSantiago Can you show your partition table?

Comment: @AkshatZala I added a screenshot of the partition table