# Freezing computer

Tags: freeze, zoom-meeting

I already looked the other answer about this kind of problem but didn't find what I need or maybe I'm so non experimented that is difficult to understand what I need to do. It's the first time I'm asking here. My computer freeze on Zoom(previously on what's app and randomly on other app) and the only way to change something to use the button to switch off and then I can see several Clearing orphaned inodes (sometime 3 sometimes 30) and then I can come back but even I sent my computer to a technician that told me that my hard drive have difficulties and he changed it, I have the same problem but less recurrent. I have 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish and I run on Asus AMDA RYZEN 5. Can you help me?

Comment: Do clean shutdowns instead of unclean shutdowns.  This isn't indicative of a hardware problem, this is indicative of you not cleanly shutting down your systems.

Comment: I do. I always shutdown by clicking right on the power to use power off. I only press the button directly when I have this problem.

Comment: So, don't press your power button directly.  If you click your power button to shut off then **that's on you** because that's an unsafe/unclean shutdown.  If it freezes on Zoom, and then you have to power-off hard then you don't have a clean system and the journal has inodes that are orphans.  Any hard-shutdown without the clean shutdown process *will* leave your system in an unclean state, and you WILL need to do a file system check (hence the orphaned inodes being cleaned and such).

Comment: Yes I understand but if I don't do my computer stays freeze forever. So what I can do to solve the freezing.

Comment: that's not the question you've asked.  rewrite your question to focus about the freeze not the "clearing orphaned inodes" issue.

Comment: I've changed the title and add some details so my computer is freezing especially on zoom (almost every time I use) and previously every time on what'app( I don't have anymore the app) and  randomly on other app.

Comment: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Ryzen#Random_reboots_with_mce_events

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, i think you're suffring the c-state bug.
https://askubuntu.com/a/803649 do the instructions right here, it works for me

Comment: Does it works ?

Comment: I did it properly then I will have to wait to use zoom or see in my day if it freezing again. Thanks

Comment: While this exact bug is a hardware bug that only affects Intel Bay Trail processors, there is/are a known bug(s) regarding c-states with Ryzen processors on newer kernels, see https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206487 . A number of solutions were listed. Interestingly, one trigger could be high CPU load (which might happen while running Zoom).\