Ubuntu 22.04 System Freezes Randomly
I'm experiencing an issue where my Ubuntu system freezes randomly, and I need help diagnosing and fixing the problem. Here are the details:
System Specifications:
Processor: Intel Core i9-12900K
RAM: DDR4 3200Mhz
GPU: RTX 3090
NVIDIA Driver Version: 535.183.01
Storage: Samsung SSD 980 PRO 1TB and ST4000NM000B-2TF
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 2204 (without GUI)
Kernel-Version: 6.5.0-44-generic
Problem Description:
My system has been freezing at random intervals. I have to do a hard reboot to get it working again. There doesn't seem to be a pattern to when the freezes occur; sometimes it happens when I'm using the terminal, and other times it occurs when the system is idle.
What I've Tried So Far:
Checked System Logs: I looked into /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log, but I couldn't find any obvious errors right before the freeze.
Updated All Packages: I made sure that my system is up to date using sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.
Additional Information:
The issue started in the last two weeks.
I haven't made any significant hardware or software changes recently.
The system runs smoothly otherwise, and the performance is generally good until the freeze happens.
Questions:

What other logs or diagnostics should I check to pinpoint the cause of the freezes?
Are there any known issues with my hardware setup and Ubuntu 22.04 that could be causing this?
What additional troubleshooting steps can I take to identify and fix the issue?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
And here are the syslog and kernel.log

Out of curiosity, I know you said you have not made significant hardware changes, but did you recently add a 2nd monitor?

No, I usually give the monitor off and connect to it via ssh

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use free to see if you have swap space.  Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

I find if I boot Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS w/only 1 monitor connected it will stay on for days. But if I boot it with 2 monitors connected it usually freezes or reboots w/in a day. I have switched out all RAM memory, Nvidia cards, power supplies, mother boards, case and processor. There is a talked about problem with Linux and AMD processors. IIRC, something about AMD not implementing suspended cores correctly. Also, there are reboot games you can play where after a Linux crash a special boot dumps RAM onto your HDD followed by a normal Linux boot. But this only works if the computer reboots.

May be this method can help you, https://askubuntu.com/a/803649/1909512, though it didn't help for me. Someone says it's a problem about new hardwares, seems too new for the kernel. However, it just happens frequently recently, within a few months.
(MY CPU i9-14900 && GPU RTX4090)
